# How effective is fake baneling burrowing at baiting scans?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-terran

Often you'll see Zerg players in ZvT burrow banelings next to marines and try to bait marines into them with mutas. But the Terran player seems to occasionally scans the area to check for burrowed banelings.

Since the mutas bait out the scan anyways, how viable is a technique to bluff burrowed banelings and bait more scans that end up being useless?

Comment: By baiting do you mean moving to the edge of their vision range and then back (ie. what Mutalisks always do)?

Comment: Yes. Usually people do that to try and get marines to walk over banes. I was saying why not burrow nothing and just get them to waste scans at virtually no cost?

Comment: when people don't burrow Banelings, how do they use Mutalisks? Is it not a back and forth motion near the edge of Terran vision?

Comment: If you're not really burrowing anything, and they don't constantly catch glimpses of you burrowing something, wouldn't they be pretty safe in assuming that you haven't burrowed anything? You'd have to invest in catching them a few times with something burrowed, and then faking the same behaviour to try to force scans out of them. If you don't give them reason to think they need to scan, then they probably won't.

Answer (score 4):

The APM you waste on trying to trick out a scan is not worth it. He might as well swap a tech lab and create a Raven to send along his arm, so he no longer needs the scans to move out. Furthermore, he only gets 240 - 270 from a [MULE](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/MULE) so you might be better of using your Mutalisks to harass unaware SCVs or perhaps pick of a Supply Depot in a corner. Your hidden Banelings on his path will catch another few marines.

Consider how you could spent the same APM on getting ahead in economy and creating a counter against what your opponent is trying to go. You could try to pick his tanks off-guard with Infestors and then roll in with some more Banelings to do a proper Baneling Bust. There are numerous of other possibilities to keep him contained or even get into his base, it all depends on what he produces...

As Sorean [mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28653/why-dont-zerg-players-bait-scans-against-terran-fake-baneling-baiting#comment-42011), you could try to work out a strategy. Play a decent amount of games where you try this out and see how you can can reform the game play you describe to be more nasty, combining:

- Forcing out stims using your Mutalisks to weaken his Bio Ball.
- Hide Banelings in key locations.
- Picking of unaware SCVs and Supply Depots.
- Take his defense down and roll in with a Baneling Bust.
- If your opponent tricks himself into a scanning pattern instead of MULEs, bonus for you!

However, keep you eye out on what he is doing. For example, don't let him counter you with Air...

Be sure to scout the map too, you don't want him to sneak in an expansion.

Answer (score 2):

If you can execute it without it affecting your macro, you should do it. It will be especially effective when you burrow Banelings later in the game.

This is often used in fighting games like Street Fighter, it is often referred to as training or educating your opponent. Basically you fake it X times. The first X-2 times he will scan, then he *learns* that you fake it. The Xth time there is a Baneling.

That said it is only worth the APM and time investment if your Mutas cannot attack more juicy targets and if you keep your macro up.

Such tricks separate the pros from the casual gamers. Do not rely on what others do, because:

- They have not figured out every possible trick
- Some tricks work better if only very few people use them